# Should org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DefaultWebSocket$WSServletRequestImpl.pathInfo be null?

Tags: java, sockets, atmosphere

When a socket connection is established via the url `/path/to/socket` should `org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets.DefaultWebSocket$WSServletRequestImpl.pathInfo` be null?  It seems like it should always contain information about the path.  I'm using `atmosphere` but am trying to debug an issue I'm experiencing.

I'm using Grizzly 2.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.grizzly/grizzly-http-servlet/1.9.56/com/sun/grizzly/http/servlet/HttpServletRequestImpl.java#HttpServletRequestImpl.getPathInfo%28%29), yes - if the relative path (after root context and servlet path are removed) is an empty string, it will return null.

Based on this, you should be able to deduce a null to mean "no path after the servlet part".

Comment: That's `com.sun.grizzly`, but the logic is likely the same.  Thanks